# Iterable of Futures using Guava?

Tags: java, guava, future

I've been working extensively with Google Guava and ListenableFutures as of late, and something I've been finding missing is a way to provide an out-of-order streaming handler of future completions. What I'm envisioning is an iterable which blocks on *next()* until another future returns.

Before I go through the effort of creating my own, does one exist already?

If not, my thought was to leverage the callback functionality of a ListenableFuture to push results onto a BlockingQueue. The goal is to process returned values as soon as they're back. `Futures.successfulAsList()` is great, but waits for all values before returning rather than letting me schedule other useful work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `java.util.concurrent.CompletionService`. Its method `take` could be easily wrapped to `Iterator.next()` if it didn't throw `InterruptedException`.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.  (Guava has considered, and rejected, having `Iterator`s that can fail, which futures definitely can -- but `CompletionService` handles the OP's needs nicely.)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you could use [the same trick I've looked at with .NET's `Task<T>`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time.aspx):

- Create a new `List<SettableFuture<T>>` values - the same number as the input futures
- Keep a counter for "how many futures have completed so far"
- For each of the input futures, add a listener so that when the future completes, it increments the counter and sets that value (or error) for the corresponding item in the list
- Return the list to the caller

That's now a sequence of futures corresponding to the input sequence, but in the order in which the inputs complete. The caller can then iterate over the list, waiting for each one to complete in turn.

Comment: This is really clever, but CompletionService seems like a better choice (despite my desire to use a Guava solution). Thank you!